# Откуда Dagger2 берет аргументы?

Tags: java, android, dagger2

Вот, есть такой метод, откуда `Dagger` будет инжектить:

```
@Module
class ModelModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ApiInterface provideApiInterface(int value, String str) {
        return ApiModule.getApiInterface(value, str);
    }
}
```

В этом методе есть 2 аргумента `int value, String str` откуда их возьмет `Dagger`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Должны быть методы предоставляющие зависимости `int` и `String`.

```
@Module
class ModelModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    int provideInt() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    String provideString() {
        return "";
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ApiInterface provideApiInterface(int value, String str) {
        return ApiModule.getApiInterface(value, str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Что то я не могу понять. Сделал так, но получаю ошибку http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587234/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-is-bound-multiple-times-%D0%B2-dagger2?noredirect=1#comment785858_587234    Можете подсказать, что сделал не так?